# High and Low times for 555 oscilator are inverted

Tags: oscillator, 555, duty-cycle

I’m new to electrical engineering and this is my first time working with an oscillator.  I'm trying to setup a 555 timer ic as an oscillator with a low time of 1s and a high time of 0.5s.  I've been using the following wire diagram, with the exception I am currently not using D2, though the results are the same with it as without it.

[image]

I'm using the following:
C1 = 10uf
R1 = 150kohm
R2 = 75kohm
A TLC555CP IC.

Every thing works except the LOW and HIGH times are the reverse of what I had expected from all the reading I have done.  I got a result of 1s on and 0.5s off.  If I reversed R1 and R2 then I got what I wanted 1s off and 0.5s on.

This seems counter to everything I've read that said R2 had to be less than R1 to get a less than 50% duty cycle. If anyone can tell me why this is I would be most appreciated.

I’ve also noticed that when power is first applied to the ic I get an instant ON that is longer than desired.  All successive ON cycles are okay.  Any suggestions for dealing with this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the output is **high** the capacitor charges through R1 (and D1) so the high time is proportional to R1.

When the output is **low** the discharge pin is also low, so the capacitor discharges through R2 (and D2, if present).

If you want high_time/low_time = 0.5/1 then R1/R2 = 0.5, so R2 should be double R1.

---

During astable operation the capacitor charges and discharges between Vcc/3 and 2Vcc/3. When first powered, the capacitor can be discharged to 0V or something near to that so the initial cycle tends to be considerably longer.

Comment: Thanks I guess I was misinterpreting what charging through R1 meant, I was thinking it meant the  output would be low then.  Thanks for clearing that up.